# Django ManyToManyField query equalivent to a list

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

I have a list of objects and a model includes ManyToManyField of this object.
I'd like to get objects who have the same list of objects in this field.
that's means __in won't work because he will do OR between the objects in the list and not AND.
I was trying using the AND Q Lookup, but it didn't work (after checking the .query text, it seems that he doing the AND inside the field object, instead of the object itself, so obviously the field object id don't have two different ids..)

here's the interceptor I played with

```
results_query_set[0]
<Results: Results object (2)>
results_query_set[0].users.all()
<QuerySet [<User: test_user>, <User: test_user_2>]>
users
[<User: test_user>, <User: test_user_2>]
users_q
<Q: (AND: ('users', <User: test_user>), ('users', <User: test_user_2>))>
results_query_set.filter(users=users[0])
<QuerySet [<Results: Results object (2)>]>
results_query_set.filter(users=users[1])
<QuerySet [<Results: Results object (2)>]>
results_query_set.filter(users_q)
<QuerySet []>
results_query_set.filter(Q(users=users[0]) & Q(users=users[1]))
<QuerySet []>
```

and the result `results_query_set.filter(users_q).query.__str__()` reproduce is

```
'SELECT "results_table"."id", "results_table"."date", "results_table"."lookup", "results_table"."value" FROM "results_table" INNER JOIN "results_table_users" ON ("results_table"."id" = "results_table_users"."widgetresults_id") WHERE ("results_table_users"."user_id" = 1 AND "results_table_users"."user_id" = 2)
```

I can chain .filter for each user, but of course, I'd like to make one query instead of queries by the numbers of my input.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @schillingt sorry, edited the tags. (postgres)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `JOIN` the target table (`User` in your case) multiple times (for every single user) in order to build such a query.

The way to do this in Django is by calling `.filter` multiple times.

```
users = [user1, user2] # a list of users your are interested to filter on
initial_qs = Results.objects.all() # or whatever your results_query_set is
result_qs = reduce(lambda qs, user: qs.filter(users=user.id), users, initial_qs)

# At this point you will have results containing user1 and user2
# but this also includes results with more users (e.g. users 1, 2 and 3)
# if you want to exclude those, you need to filter by the total users count too
result_qs = result_qs.annotate(cnt=models.Count('users')).filter(cnt=len(users))
```

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, but wanted to prevent this and thought maybe django have a better clean solution.

Comment: This solutions seems pretty clean to me I'm not sure how much cleaner you want it to be, however just read your question again, chaining/calling `.filter` multiple times does not make multiple queries, your query is still one, but with multiple joins. If you really want to have a single `join` then maybe your best options would be to annotate the `ids` with something like `group_concat` (not supported by django by default) and then filter on this annotation, however this will definitely be slower than multiple joins.

Comment: interesting. why will it be slower? sounds like O(n)

Comment: The filtration will happen inside SQL  `HAVING` Clause, after all records are fetched and the annotated value gets calculated, with multiple joins the RDBMS knows exactly what needs to be fetched and how to maximally optimize for the records that need to be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but I think you might be able to use postgresql's `array_agg` function. The Django implementation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg).

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

ideal_user_list = [] # some list. 
                     # Or fetch it directly from the db using the below query and `get`
Results.objects.annotate(
    related_user_array=ArrayAgg('users__id', ordering='users__id')
).filter(related_user_array=ideal_user_list)
```

Comment: not working and throwing an exception of `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "serial[]" does not exist`